# MySql db assign null to the variable at initializion

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, procedure

Here i want to assign null to my Nfcno and Mobileno variables but its showing error at '='

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Sp_GetCustomerId`(
Nfcno nvarchar(20)= Null ,
Mobileno nvarchar(20)=Null )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the error message you're getting to your question.

Comment: syntax error :@=Null